Disable native compilation for multiplatform dependency
I have a backend project that uses ktor on the JVM. It depends on a multiplatform project like so:
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":api"))
}

Now when building the project in CI I see this:
> Configure project :api
Please wait while Kotlin/Native compiler 1.9.20 is being installed.
Download https://download.jetbrains.com/kotlin/native/builds/releases/1.9.20/linux-x86_64/kotlin-native-prebuilt-linux-x86_64-1.9.20.tar.gz (198.16 MB)
Download kotlin-native-prebuilt-linux-x86_64-1.9.20.tar.gz finished, took 2 s 786 ms
Unpack Kotlin/Native compiler to /root/.konan/kotlin-native-prebuilt-linux-x86_64-1.9.20
Unpack Kotlin/Native compiler to /root/.konan/kotlin-native-prebuilt-linux-x86_64-1.9.20 finished, took 4 s 513 ms
w: The following Kotlin/Native targets cannot be built on this machine and are disabled:
iosArm64, iosSimulatorArm64, iosX64
To hide this message, add 'kotlin.native.ignoreDisabledTargets=true' to the Gradle properties.

I actually dont want the build to waste time here on the native target. How can I avoid this?
I am no expert in gradle and I did not find any obvious configuration options to remove not needed targets.
